# How to update all object columns in SqlAlchemy?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I have a table of Users(more than 15 columns) and sometimes I need to completely update all the user attributes.For xample, I want to replace

`user_in_db = session.query(Users).filter_by(user_twitter_iduser.user_twitter_id).first()`
with some other object.

I have found the following solution :

```
session.query(User).filter_by(id=123).update({"name": user.name})
```

but I fell that writing all 15+ attributes is error-prone and there should exist a simpler solution.

Comment: You could dynamically create the dictionary without having to write out all column names in code.

Comment: @SimeonVisser  [{f:getattr(t,f)} for f in vars(t) if f.find('_')!=0] something like that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write:

```
session.query(User).filter_by(id=123).update({column: getattr(user, column) for column in User.__table__.columns.keys()})
```

This will iterate over the columns of the `User` model (table) and it'll dynamically create a dictionary with the necessary keys and values.

Comment: Thanks! It works. By the way, it looks like you forgot "}" bracket after first ")". Can you add it?

Comment: How would you prevent it from trying to update the primary_key column?